# Get the scaling percent in windows

Tags: c++, screenshot

We can get the screen size using the following MFC code;

```
GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), (CRect)rect);
```

And we can change the screen scale using the windows Settings --> System --> Display --> Scale and layout --> "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" .
This ComboBox includes 100%(Recommended), 125% 175% etc.

When I changed to 125% or 175%, I cannot get the correct screenshot.
The sceenshot will be cutted.

How can i get that screen scaling value, or how can i get the correct screenshot at all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is due to [DPI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) which normalizes coordinates by default so that apps don't need to be aware of scaling.

This can be avoided by:

- [Enabling DPI awareness in the manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/C9488338-D863-45DF-B5CB-7ED9B869A5E2#Setting_default_awareness_with_the_application_manifest).
- Or setting DPI awareness with an [API call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/C9488338-D863-45DF-B5CB-7ED9B869A5E2#Setting_default_awareness_programmatically) such as  [SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext).

Comment: okay, i found the option in VS Manifest Tool -> DPI Awareness.